# Push Notifications - Single Server multiple apps

Tags: push-notification

We have a SSL set up on one server, and we have several apps we are about to put push notifications in. Can I use the same server for each of these apps?

There currently is not a problem, just trying to investigate as we enter into this. I have searched these and other forums without any luck so far to others discussing it. Any links to documentations for this would be greatly appreciated.

Craig

Comment: Please improve your question. Provide us with more specific details, a better description of your problem, and what you tried to find out the answer yourself.

Comment: What OS is the server running? Which client platform(s) will your applications run on? What is the expected number of notifications per client? What is the expected size of the notification? Are you asking if you can have more than one client or different client applications? Are the different applications expected to use the same notification service or will there be concurrent services running on the same server?

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon the server, the client and the apps, but the short answer is: Yes you can.

Comment: Bryan, thanks for your response. Any thoughts on where I can find any specifics on this?

Comment: I honestly don't know the context of your original question, so I am unable to point you in any direction other than "google".